# How to Display Strings in BlackBox on top of the Screen, Java?

Tags: java, string, splash-screen

I need to create an alarm program in Java:
I don't how to pop up string in the middle of the screen for 30 seconds
in black box.
Just like Rhythumbox notifcation.
Also how on close the program minimized in the notification area (ubuntu)
I just don't know where to start, the alarm code is easy, just those 2 functions.
please help

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at:

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for details about how to create a UI using Swing
- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) as a possible alternative to other timer mechnisms.  The benefit of this is that it is executed within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, so you don't need to mess to much about re-syncing the UI code with the EDT when the timer goes off.  May not suit your requirements, but it's nice to know.
- [How to Use the System Tray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html)

**Updated**

- Create a `JWindow`.
- Set the background color of the content pane to `Color.BLACK`
- Set the [`alwaysOnTop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)) to `true`
- Create a `JLabel`, set it's `text` property and change it's `foreground` color to something like `Color.WHITE`, adjust what ever other properties you
- Add a `Border` to the content if you want to add some padding
- Add the label to the content pane
- `pack` the window
- set it's `locationRelativeTo` `null`, to make it appear in the center of the screen
- Make the window visible

Possible examples...

- [How to make a transparent JFrame but keep everything else the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927980/how-to-make-a-transparant-jframe-in-java-but-keep-everything-else-the-same/14928212#14928212)
- [Java transparent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844927/java-transparent-window/11853691#11853691)
- [How to draw images on transparent window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771215/how-to-draw-images-on-transparent-window/21771615#21771615)

Comment: Thank you. I know how to use swing with/without netbeans. I need to find the method that display string on top of screen in black box.

Comment: `JLabel` on a `JWindow`...

Comment: Sir, I am sorry, I didn't make myself clear, I need when the time is up a notification String pops up on the screen on the top of any other programs being used, like chrome, office, anything, not inside the same program, that would be a peace of cake

Comment: like this picture, if you know Rhythumbox: http://tinypic.com/r/t00q5h/8